# Difference arr[range(3)] vs arr[:3] in numpy

Tags: python

I have a script easy code, so i don't know why elements in numpy don't swap.
Thank you ^^

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(10)

a = arr[range(3)]
b = arr[:3]
c = arr[3:6]

# Can swap
arr[range(3)], arr[3:6] = arr[3:6],arr[range(3)] 

# Can't swap
arr[:3], arr[3:6] = arr[3:6],arr[:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Basic slices in numpy are **views** of part of the array, whereas advanced indexing creates a **copy** of the relevant part of the array.

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> Advanced indexing always returns a copy of the data (contrast with
> basic slicing that returns a view).

`arr[range(3)]` is an example of advanced indexing.  You can see this if you try to assign to elements of `a`:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> a = arr[range(3)]
>>> a[0] = 11
>>> a
array([11,  1,  2])
>>> arr
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

by contrast, `arr[:3]` is a basic slice, and gives a view of the array:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> b = arr[:3]
>>> b[0] = 11
>>> b
array([11,  1,  2])
>>> arr
array([11,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```

Trying to swap using two views of the array does not work, because the temporary tuple similarly contains two views of the array.  You have no separate temporary copy of the data, as would be needed to perform the swap correctly.

In fact to perform the swap correctly, you do not need the advanced indexing on the left-hand side of the assignment.  It is sufficient to do it only on the right-hand side:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> arr[:3], arr[3:6] = arr[3:6],arr[range(3)] 
>>> arr
array([3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Or make a copy:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(10)
>>> arr[:3], arr[3:6] = arr[3:6],arr[:3].copy()
>>> arr
array([3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: thank you for answer, so can i ask you a question?
list arr still keep value when i change c[1]


>>> arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

>>> c = arr[:]

>>> c[1] = 4
#print arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: @superbrain I'll rephrase slightly with "similarly" instead of also. I meant "also" as in "just like in the above example", rather than "in addition to something else in the same statement".

Comment: @Quang.tpa Your `arr` in the example in the comment just here is a list, not a numpy array. Try it with `arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])` and you will see a difference. Slices of *lists* are copies.

Comment: Could you expand on `Trying to swap using two views of the array does not work...`? Why two views of the same array can't be  saved on the stack?

Comment: @yatu The views are exactly that: views. Even if these sliced array objects are saved somewhere, e.g. a temporary 2-element tuple, they still point to the original array object when it comes to extracting the values. Once you have copied `arr[3:6]` into `arr[:3]` you no longer have the original contents of `arr[:3]` anywhere.